# Serverless PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, serverless, multi-master-replication

I'm trying to setup a "Serverless" PostgreSQL data replication architecture.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I'm trying to install a PostgreSQL database in every machine and then have that data synchronize between all available servers.

I've tried SymmetricDS but it does not allow me to do a mesh type network.
I'm currently trying [EDB Replication Server](https://www.enterprisedb.com/products/replication), but I need to have a centralized point to install the server. If it were possible to install the server on every machine and then have it sync between each other would be great, but it doesn't seem possible.

Any tips on how to achieve Multi-master "serverless" architecture in postgresql? Any success stories and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this "serverless" if you are planning to have multiple servers? But there is no free multi-master replication solution available for Postgres.

Comment: I don't want it to be a dedicated server, I want it all to be hosted client side, technically there are servers, but it should be the computers with the apps, not dedicated machines. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: It's still a server if it runs Postgres. In my opinion "serverless" is most stupid buzz word ever.

Comment: I agree lol, but yeah, I'm looking to have decentralized servers, if that makes sense.